# How can I detect any variable that is passed to a function that is not explicitly whitelisted by naming the variable in a custom attribute in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a fun one.

I would like to write a function (which will become a test) that will return false (the test will fail) whenever any Action Method passes any variable to any function unless that variable is explicitly named by passing it's name to a custom attribute that decorates the action method.

In the example below, the function should not fail due to `myParam1` being passed to the `GetData` function because `myParam1`'s name is passed to the `CustomAttribute` that decorates the function, but it should fail (or return false) due to `myVar1`'s name not being passed to the `CustomAttribute`.

```
[CustomAttribute("myParam1")]
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionMethod(string myParam1, int myParam2)
{
    var myVar1 =    "value";
    return myService.GetData(myParam1, myVar1);
}
```

Why? The `CustomAttribute` is a custom authorization attribute and the plan is to ensure we do not accidentally pass an ID/key that we should not be passed to a service, unless the user has authorization to access the date relating to that key.

Comment: If i didn't misunderstood what you want that's a case for static code analysis and not something you do in a (unit)test.

Comment: In that case can you provide a solution for doing this with static code analysis?

Comment: Not really i don't think existing analysis tools will know about anything of your custom attributes and will act accordingly. You would need to write your own one. But i'm just guessing (maybe also the reason of the downvotes) because the question is unclear. You want to connect the parameter values of your CustomAttribute with the variable names (not their values) that `myService.GetData` is called with? That would need code analysis as that is not information you can get from compiled code and reflection.

Answer (score -4):

Pls don't invent a wheel

```
public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyActionMethod(string myParam1, int myParam2)
{
    if (myParam1==null) return BadRequest("myParam1 is nulll");
     .....
}
```